# How to convert buffer to image with react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, base64, buffer

**I am using pouchdb with react native (expo) to store the local data and also the images and when trying to recover the image I get the following data**

```
Object {                                                                                                                                                                  
    "data": Array [                                                                                                                                                           
          161,                                                                                                                                                                    
          184,                                                                                                                                                                    
          222,                                                                                                                                                                    
          114,                                                                                                                                                                    
          211,                                                                                                                                                                    
          155,                                                                                                                                                                    
          141,                                                                                                                                                                    
          231,                                                                                                                                                                    
          45,                                                                                                                                                                   
     ],                                                                                                                                                                      
     "type": "Buffer",                                                                                                                                                     
 }
```

I would like to convert this return to an image. I already tried to use methods like this in an attempt to get a base64 and so the image later:

```
let base64String = new Buffer.from(result).toString("base64")
```

But what I get in return is this

```
objectObject
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I solved like so.

`response` is your API result and then I returned it like this:

`return Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64)`

Comment: In react native with this solution if anyone get error like "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer". Use like below
const mBuffer = (global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer);

return mBuffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using libraries suchas `react-native-buffer` to simulate buffers in a react native environment. With that installed, you can now use the buffer as if it's a regular `Buffer` in a nodejs script

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be because you're `result.data` property is already a Buffer array. Try just calling `toString` on it directly:

```js
let base64String = result.data.toString('base64');
```

Btw thanks for this question, I couldn't find an answer for how to convert a Uint8Array into a base64 string anywhere!